# Поиск в json_decode

Tags: php, массивы

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(18) "241667244927483904" ["name"]=> string(9) "LuckPerms" ["icon"]=> string(32) "f2693325e1d62997cdbc6b101790b631" ["owner"]=> bool(false) ["permissions"]=> int(104188992) ["features"]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(22) "WELCOME_SCREEN_ENABLED" [1]=> string(12) "DISCOVERABLE" [2]=> string(27) "ENABLED_DISCOVERABLE_BEFORE" [3]=> string(9) "COMMUNITY" [4]=> string(4) "NEWS" [5]=> string(10) "VANITY_URL" [6]=> string(15) "PREVIEW_ENABLED" [7]=> string(8) "VERIFIED" [8]=> string(13) "INVITE_SPLASH" [9]=> string(10) "FEATURABLE" } ["permissions_new"]=> string(9) "104188992" } [1]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(18) "443008538269450250" ["name"]=> string(11) "FreeMC.Host" ["icon"]=> string(32) "aa9fe86efa7bbc37ffe82455c421ad06" ["owner"]=> bool(false) ["permissions"]=> int(3263489) ["features"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "NEWS" [1]=> string(22) "WELCOME_SCREEN_ENABLED" [2]=> string(13) "INVITE_SPLASH" [3]=> string(13) "ANIMATED_ICON" [4]=> string(9) "COMMUNITY" } ["permissions_new"]=> string(7) "3263489" } [2]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(18) "633716675354820608" ["name"]=> string(13) "FaithCraft RP" ["icon"]=> string(34) "a_5587d130a118db3b73617245828c3336" ["owner"]=> bool(false) ["permissions"]=> int(2147483647) ["features"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "NEWS" [1]=> string(22) "WELCOME_SCREEN_ENABLED" [2]=> string(13) "INVITE_SPLASH" [3]=> string(13) "ANIMATED_ICON" [4]=> string(9) "COMMUNITY" } ["permissions_new"]=> string(10) "2147483647" } }
```

Есть полученный ответ в array. Как мне, допустим, получить отсюда нужный `id` со значением `633716675354820608`

Comment: Где ваш код, который покажет нам что вы хотя бы пытались самостоятельно подумать о решении?

Comment: Серьёзно? Чтобы ответить на вопрос надо самому переделать объект в такой вид, который можно в код вставить?

Comment: Приведите код массива, который можно взять, скопировать и выполнить. Этот вывод что руками переписывать?

Comment: мышкой и ctrl + c

Comment: @ГлебЧерных, ctrl+c - не проблема, но вот ctrl+v на php не компилируется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$res = array_filter($arr, function ($x) { return $x['id'] == '633716675354820608'; })
```